# How to configure Sailsjs on subfolder using proxypass?

Tags: node.js, nginx, sails.js, proxypass

I run Laravel on Nginx server and want to setup Sailjs on subfolder example.com/sailsapp/

In nginx config I have following

```
location /sailsapp {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
}
```

by visiting example.com/sailsapp/ I would expect  `'/': { view: 'pages/homepage' },` route to load homepage but instead I get 404.

if I change Sailjs  `'/sailsapp': { view: 'pages/homepage' }`, homepage view loads fine, but the problem is that all assets point to example.com and not `example.com/sailsapp` which is my main issue.

How can I configure sails app, so it would actually know what is the real base of the aplication rather take the top level domain as base.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to achieve what I needed.

In Nginx config I needed to add rewrite, to simply rewrite `/sailsapp/(.*)` to `/$1`  This allowed to proxy request correctly.

```
location /sailsapp {
        rewrite /sailsapp/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
}
```

It still didn't help with the assets though.

To configure auto inject assets on Sails I went to `tasks/config/sails-linker.js`
and changed `fileTmpl: '<script src="%s"></script>',` to `fileTmpl: '<script src="/sailsapp%s"></script>'`,

Not sure if I will come across more issues, but this actually allows me to move forward with my app build.